# Determining logic to break down cards horizontally in bootsrap

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following piece of code which essentially creates bootstrap 4 cards dynamically after obtaining some values from a db. The problem is however each new entry keeps getting stacked horizontally and I am struggling to write a piece of logic to tell the html to break a new line to stack cards once its more than 3 cards.
Here is what I have so far, really appreciate some guidance on it

```
<div class="row row-container">
<?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>

<div class="col">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">
<?php echo $row->title?></h5>
<p class="card-text"><?php echo $row->ID?></p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
```

My initial code that works fine other than the fact that it keeps stacking new elements horizontally.Essentailly to break a new row I need a new line of `<div class="row row-container">` which is what I cant think of at the moment on how to get.

I tried adding the logic as below which would check using a count variable whether the number of items is divisible by 3 or not (it should break a new row if it is) but I dont know how to conttine

```
<div class="row row-container">
        <?php $count=0; ?>
            <?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
            <?php

                $count++
                ?>

            <?php
            if (($count % 3) ==0 ){
                echo "<div class="row row-container">";
            }

                echo "$count" ?>
            <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row->title ?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $row->description ?></p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this, but if the sole purpose is to ensure that every 4th column goes to a new row, I would use `array_chunk` to achieve this:

```php
<?php foreach (array_chunk($data, 3) as $row) : ?>
<div class="row row-container">
    <?php foreach ($row as $col) : ?>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                <?php echo $col->title?></h5>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo $col->ID?></p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here's a [live demo](https://php-fiddle.com/5fabbda0d7459/1) for your quick reference.

The `array_chunk` function breaks an array into smaller chuncks. More details are available at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Comment: wow incredible! So many things to learn here, thanks for your well explained answer @Matt